# Switch back to my app when inactivity is detected across system

Tags: android, adb

Currently have rooted android devices running our application which was built through android studio.

We are looking to add in functionality that would make it so that the devices would switch back to our application if inactivity was detected on any other application or any part of the system.

Currently we do have it so the devices will switch back to our application if it is closed or not in the foreground, we'd want to change this so it would only switch back to our application if inactivity was detected

Comment: Why have you used `adb` tag? Is the device connected all the time to a computer via adb?